# How to make Thunderbird suggest favorite contacts first when sending mails?

Tags: thunderbird, ldap, address-book

My Thunderbird client is connected to the rather large LDAP directory of our company. When I start typing in the "To:" field, it lists all matching LDAP entries alphabetically. This list is very long until I'm done typing the entire name.

I send mails only to 0,01% of the people in my company, so I would prefer if it would **first** suggest entries

- I used most in the past
- from my local address book

Are there any add-ons / tools / configs. for this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thunderbird already looks at your local address book first. You can perhaps have it add the e-mail addresses found in the directory to the local address book so they would be found first (and faster)?

```
Tools -> Preferences -> Composition -> Addressing -> (Check) Local Address Books + (Check) Directory Server + (Check) Automatically add outgoing e-mail addresses to my (Personal/Collected) Address book
```